# One syntaxe to regroupe 4 or more conditions in EXCEL

Tags: excel

I am using EXCEL, to sum up, the total scores of questions answered in a test, the end result is a score, but it does not help much as I'd like to regroup students based on the test in 4 or more groups, like A, B, C, D groups.
For this end, I have 4 conditions :

Condition 1: If the score is less or equal to 20 then result is A

Condition 2: If the score is more than 20 or less equal to 40 then result is B

Condition 3: If the score is more than 40 or less equal to 60 then result is C

Condition 4: If score is more than 60 then result is D

The idea here is to translate the scores based on conditions in one syntax and applied to hundred of students at once
I am a newbie in excel so I find it difficult task, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways:

1. See the picture as the example, make a table under `columns E and F`, then under `column C`, enter the formula `=VLOOKUP(B2,$E$2:$F$5,2,1)` then drag/copy it down to the end of records.  You should see the reults like I have here.  The benefit for this is when the group score changes in `column E or F`, you don't need to change anything in `column C`.

[image]

2. See the picture below, similar to example 1, but instead of using a table as a reference, the formula is derived directly.  Just enter the formula in `cell C2` and then drag/copy down to the end.

`=IF(B2>60,"D",IF(B2>40,"C",IF(B2>20,"B","A")))`

[image]

Not sure which way you like more but give it a shot.  Let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using nested `=IF` statments.

`=IF(B1<=80,IF(B1<=60,IF(B1<=40,IF(B1<=20,"A","B"),"C"),"D"),"D")`

Where B1 is replaced for the cell that has the score, and needs to be grouped.